# ASP.NET 5 Application Reference .NET 4.6 DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to reference a .NET 4.6.1 dll from my ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update1 project.  I cannot, and I think the reason is that it's referencing DNX 4.5.1.  I think it should be referencing DNX46...  How do I change that?  Do I need to install DNX46 myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `project.json` file, if you try and reference a `.NET 4.6.1` class project or file, and your main project is set to `.NET 4.5.1`, it wont let you. Just change it like this.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx461": { }
},
```